# WordPress monthly archive page takes me to homepage

Tags: wordpress, archive

I am having problem in my site http://www.sopel.com/giant-pearl-discovered/ , when I click on any month, it takes me back to my homepage but instead I want the links to go to those monthly archive page. I am using  function, what could be the problem??

Comment: are you use any plugins?

Comment: no, not using any plugin for categories, what is actually happening here? I just have no idea...

Comment: is there any customisation with code?

Comment: You must set permalink to %postname%

Comment: if above fails then try this plugin , https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-type-archive-links/

Comment: I tried both suggestion but not work .

Comment: can you post your archive page??

Comment: yes i did it :) and thank you so much for your help !!